# Show elements on hover with CSS

Tags: html, css, hover, hide, show-hide

I want to show 2 elements (one div, inside it one buttom) when I hover an image. I got some problems: It didn't works!

My HTML code:

```
<div class="discord-container">
    <center>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/7K3OLPH.png", class="discord-image", width="75"/>
    <div class="discord-poupup" id="poupup-element">
      <button onClick="discord.logout()" class="logout-button" id="poupup-element">LOGOUT</button>
    </div>
    </center>
  </div>
```

On CSS:

```
.discord-image {
  border: solid #7289DA;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

img.discord-image:hover + div#poupup-element:hover {
  display:block;
}

#poupup-element{
  display: none;
}
```

The 'discord-poupup' class on div just change background colors and positions, it don't touch on display.

Well, I want to show everything with id 'poupup-element' when I hover the image with class 'discord-image' (and preferably keep it showing while the mouse cursor is hoving it AND its already active). I tried lots of things, but nothing works :c Can someone help-me?

(I'm also using Shiny (from R lang). If there is an easier way to do what I want please tell-me)

Answer (score 1):

I guess there was an issue with your HTML. You should not have two same ID's.  Also you should not put commas in your HTML tags.

here's the solution

### css:

```
#poupup-element{
  display:none;
}
.discord-image:hover + #poupup-element{
  display:block;
}
```

Edit:

### html

```
 <div class="discord-container">
  <center>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/7K3OLPH.png" class="discord-image"  width="75" />
    <div class="discord-poupup" id="poupup-element">
      <button onClick="discord.logout()" class="logout-button" >LOGOUT</button>
    </div>
  </center>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Like others already mentioned, 'id' should be unique. You could try giving your div and button a class called "poupup-element".
Also, you have commas in your img tag that should not be there.

**HTML**

```html
<div class="discord-container">
  <center>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/7K3OLPH.png" class="discord-image" width="75"/>
    <div class="discord-poupup poupup-element">
      <button onClick="discord.logout()" class="logout-button poupup-element">LOGOUT</button>
    </div>
  </center>
</div>
```

```css
.discord-image {
  border: solid #7289DA;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
.poupup-element{
  display: none;
}
img.discord-image:hover .poupup-element {
  display:block;
}
```